# How would I return a count of all rows in the table and then the count of each time a specific status is found?

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

Please forgive my ignorance on sqlalchemy, up until this point I've been able to navigate the seas just fine.  What I'm looking to do is this:

- Return a count of how many items are in the table.
- Return a count of many times different statuses appear in the table.

I'm currently using sqlalchemy, but even a pure sqlite solution would be beneficial in figuring out what I'm missing.

Here is how my table is configured:

```
class KbStatus(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

It's a very basic table but I'm having a hard time getting back the data I'm looking for.  I have this working with 2 separate queries, but I have to believe there is a way to do this all in one query.

Here are the separate queries I'm running:

```
total = len(cls.query.all())
status_count = cls.query.with_entities(KbStatus.status, func.count(KbStatus.id).label("total")).group_by(KbStatus.status).all()
```

From here I'm converting it to a dict and combining it to make the output look like so:

```
{
  "data": {
    "status_count": {
        "Assigned": 1,
        "In Progress": 1,
        "Peer Review": 1,
        "Ready to Publish": 1,
        "Unassigned": 4
    },
    "total_requests": 8
  }
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about sqlalchemy, but it's possible to generate the results you want in a single query with pure sqlite using the [JSON1](https://sqlite.org/json1.html) extension:

Given the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, status TEXT);
INSERT INTO data(status) VALUES ('Assigned'),('In Progress'),('Peer Review'),('Ready to Publish')
                               ,('Unassigned'),('Unassigned'),('Unassigned'),('Unassigned');
CREATE INDEX data_idx_status ON data(status);
```

this query

```
WITH individuals AS (SELECT status, count(status) AS total FROM data GROUP BY status)
SELECT json_object('data'
                 , json_object('status_count'
                              , json_group_object(status, total)
                              , 'total_requests'
                              , (SELECT sum(total) FROM individuals)))
FROM individuals;
```

will return one row holding (After running through a JSON pretty printer; the actual string is more compact):

```js
{
  "data": {
    "status_count": {
      "Assigned": 1,
      "In Progress": 1,
      "Peer Review": 1,
      "Ready to Publish": 1,
      "Unassigned": 4
    },
    "total_requests": 8
  }
}
```

---

If the sqlite instance you're using wasn't  built with support for JSON1:

```
SELECT status, count(status) AS total FROM data GROUP BY status;
```

will give

```
status                total
--------------------  ----------
Assigned              1
In Progress           1
Peer Review           1
Ready to Publish      1
Unassigned            4
```

which you can iterate through in python, inserting each row into your dict and adding up all `total` values in another variable as you go to get the `total_requests` value at the end. No need for another query just to calculate that number; do it manually. I bet it's really easy to do the same thing with your existing second sqlachemy query.